# how to execute a command in a running command in bash

Tags: linux, bash, docker, postgresql

how to execute this commands in bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec -ti test psql db db
drop schema if exists stack cascade;            
delete from partman.part_config; 
\q
pwd
cd /folder/name
```

Comment: Yes, i want do it in bash script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send lines from your script to the input of a program you should use a "here doc". In this example it's ended with `EOD`

```
#!/bin/bash
docker exec test psql db db  << 'EOD'
drop schema if exists stack cascade;            
delete from partman.part_config; 
\q
EOD
pwd
cd /folder/name
```

You can then continue the script as before.

```
chmod a+rx theScript    # Make the script executable
./theScript             # Run it
```

However, if you run this as a true script the last `cd` will have little useful effect, as it cannot change the directory for the calling process (your shell).

There are many solutions here on StackExchange but the general approach is that the `cd` must be run in the current process context. You do that by running the script via *dot*:

```
. theScript             # Source the script
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning heredoc, I didn't know what it was or how it worked, but that's exactly what I need. 
However, I get an error when running the script `the input device is not a TTY`

Comment: That'll be coming from your `docker` command. I'm not terribly familiar with `docker` but you might want to try removing the `-t` and/or `-i` flags (see `man docker`)

Comment: thanks you, now its work when i removing the  `-t` flag